# *ngFor with sub array

Tags: angular, ngfor, formarray

(Sorry for this subject, but I don't think much of anything else)

Hi there,
i get JSON datas in the following way:

```
{
(... some stuff...)

"credentials": {
    "credential": [{
        "username": "Peter",
        "password": "dummy1"
    }, {
        "username": "Marc",
        "password": "dummy2"
    }, {
        "username": "Oliver",
        "password": "dummy3"
    }, {
        "username": "Tom",
        "password": "dummy4"
    }, {
        "username": "Brian",
        "password": "dummy5"
    }]
}
```

}

and i want to display them with *ngFor like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, FormArray, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="form">
      <input type="checkbox" formControlName="published"> Published
      <div *ngIf="form.controls.published.value">

        <h2>Credentials</h2>
        <button (click)="addCreds()">Add</button>

        <div formArrayName="credentials" *ngFor="let creds of form.controls.credentials?.value; let i = index">
          <ng-container [formGroupName]="i">
            <input placeholder="Username" formControlName="username">
            <input placeholder="Password" formControlName="password">
          </ng-container>
        </div>

      </div>
    </form>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent  {
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      published: true,
      // credentials: {credential: new FormArray([])}
      credentials: {credential: this.fb.array([])}
    });
  }

  addCreds() {
    const creds = this.form.controls.credentials as FormArray;
    // const creds = this.form.controls.credentials.value.credential as FormArray;
    creds.push(this.fb.group({
      username: '',
      password: '',
    }));
  }
}
```

But this doesn't work. :-(
Q: How can i display all `credentials` with *ngFor? Important for me ist only *ngFor in this case.

Thank you in advance and greetings Filout

Comment: what is the error you are facing??

Comment: `ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.`

Answer (score 1):

Write in ts.

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
  published: true 
  credentials: this.fb.array([])}
});

 get credentials() {
      return this.form.get('credentials') as FormArray
```

In html

```
*ngFor="let creds of credentials?.controls; ......
```

Comment: Exactly this is my problem. 

`credentials` doesn't have a `controls => credential`, only a `value =>credential`.

Comment: change credentials: {credential: this.fb.array([])} in credentials: this.fb.array([]) and it will work :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i know this, but this is (unfortunately) not the solution for me, because the server will have back the datas in this format.
Otherwise i get an server error while saving